# ETL using Azure Data Factory v2

Tags: azure, ssis, etl, azure-data-factory

I just want to ask what is the proper approach and sample components to be used when you are performing an ETL and will be using Azure Data Factory v2. Will still there be a need to use SSIS or can Azure Data Factory handle all the processes in the pipelines to be used for an ETL solution ?

Thanks for answering everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question will be specific to your circumstances. Azure Data Factory is an orchestrator. As such, it doesn't "do" ETL*, rather it manages other services to do the work. The workers, therefore, be SSIS, or Stored Procedures, or U-SQL scripts, or Azure Batch, or any number of available activity types. So you do not *need* SSIS, but you can certainly still leverage it if it makes sense in your scenario.

*The exception is the ADF Copy activity that will allow you to specify a source and a sink and move data from one to the other.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already familiar with SSIS/have existing SSIS ETL packages, you can simply lift & shift them into SSIS in ADF (Azure-SSIS Integration Runtime).  If you don't want to use SSIS, ADF ETL/data flow feature will be introduced soon and is currently under preview.